# Error importing 'next/headers' in Next.js 14 'src/utils.ts'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

inside `src/utils.ts`

```js
import { type ClassValue, clsx } from "clsx";
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";
import { SignJWT, jwtVerify } from "jose";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";`
```

```js
./src/utils.ts
Error: 
  × You're importing a component that needs next/headers. That only works in a Server Component which is not supported in the pages/ directory. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/
  │ react-essentials#server-components
  │ 
  │ 
   ╭─[D:\Projects\Programming\supermuslim-dashboard-nextjs\src\utils.ts:2:1]
 2 │ import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";
 3 │ import { SignJWT, jwtVerify } from "jose";
 4 │ import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
 5 │ import { cookies } from "next/headers";
   · ───────────────────────────────────────
```

This is my src directory tree

```
│   middleware.ts
│   utils.ts
│
├───app
│   │   favicon.ico
│   │   globals.css
│   │   layout.tsx
│   │   page.tsx
│   │
│   ├───(auth)
│   │   │   layout.tsx
│   │   │
│   │   └───signin
│   │           page.tsx
│   │
│   └───dashboard
│           page.tsx
│
├───components
│   │   ModeToggle.tsx
│   │   Navbar.tsx
│   │
│   ├───Forms
│   │       LogInForm.tsx
│   │       RememberMeCheckbox.tsx
│   │       SignUpForm.tsx
│   │
│   └───ui
│           button.tsx
│           checkbox.tsx
│           dropdown-menu.tsx
│           form.tsx
│           input.tsx
│           label.tsx
│           toast.tsx
│           toaster.tsx
│           use-toast.ts
│
├───interfaces
│       index.ts
│
├───providers
│       theme-provider.tsx
│
└───server-actions
    └───auth
            actions.ts
```

There's a function inside `utils.ts` that is invoked on every request through `middleware.ts`. I'm unable to identify the root cause of the error. My implementation is similar to the code in this repository:
https://github.com/balazsorban44/auth-poc-next/blob/main/lib.ts

Comment: Hi Mustapha! Have you checked the below answer? Let us know please :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is my layout.tsx for my wallet connect project where I need to pass headers in my context provider. Please consider this example.

```
import './globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { headers } from 'next/headers'

import { cookieToInitialState } from 'wagmi'

import { config } from '@/config'
import { ContextProvider } from '@/context'

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app'
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode
}>) {
  const initialState = cookieToInitialState(config, headers().get('cookie'))
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <ContextProvider initialState={initialState}>{children}</ContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

It's just an example, how you can pass headers in root layout. Let me know if this works for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies) doesn't seem to mention the use of the `cookies()` function in a middleware (even tough it's not a “don't”):

> The cookies function allows you to read the HTTP incoming request cookies from a [Server Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components) or write outgoing request cookies in a [Server Action](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations) or [Route Handler](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers).

Also, on the middleware [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#using-cookies), they don't use the `cookies()` function, but rather the request itself:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
 
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  let token = request.cookies.get('token')
  utlilFunction(token) // Pass it to your function in util
  return NextResponse.next()
}
```